# How to make a div hidden initially and load when input is entered?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

HTML:

```html
<span class="searchTextarea">          
  <input type="text" (keyup)="testlist($event, searchType)" 
         (keydown.enter)="Results($event)" autocomplete="off" id="searchcontent" 
         name="searchcontents" [(ngModel)]="searchcontent" minlength="3" maxlength="5000"
         placeholder="{{translations.Placeholder}}" autofocus list="filllList">
  <div class="searchListarea">
    <ul id="filllList" *ngIf="Results">            
      <li *ngFor="let result" [innerHTML]="result" (click)="Selectitem($event)" ></li>            
    </ul>
  </div>
</span>
```

CSS:

```css
.searchListarea{
    display:none;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    ul{
        display:inline
    }
}
```

When I insert text to the input, the suggestion list is not appearing. If I remove `display:none`, its appearing but it always displays (even before inserting text).

I want the list to appear on input entry else it should disappear.

Comment: what exactly do you want hidden? the searchlist area or what?

Comment: you are correct i want to hide search list area on no entered text is found a match in binded results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you only want the user to see the search results when they press enter and there are search results and the search query is not empty.

I feel this search can be implemented in a better way. You're using styles and `innerHTML` in order to show/hide the search results.

But you can do that using the Component Class properties as well.

Here is how your Component Class would look like:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [
    // Add other properties to the objects below
    { name: "Leanne Graham" },
    ...
  ];
  query;
  showResults = false;
  searchResults = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetSearchResults();
  }

  prepareSearchResults(searchType) {
    this.showResults = false;
    this.setSearchResults(this.items.filter(item => item[searchType].toUpperCase().indexOf(this.query.toUpperCase()) > -1));
  }

  setSearchResults(searchResults) {
    this.searchResults = [...searchResults];
  }

  resetSearchResults() {
    this.showResults = false;
    this.searchResults = [...this.items];
  }

  selectItem(item) {
    // do something here
  }

}
```

And then in your template:

```
<span class="searchTextarea">
  <input 
    type="text" 
    (keyup)="$event.code !== 'Enter' && prepareSearchResults('name')" 
    (keydown.enter)="showResults = true"
    autocomplete="off" 
    id="searchcontent" 
    name="searchcontents" 
    [(ngModel)]="query"
    minlength="3"
    maxlength="5000" 
    placeholder="Search"
    autofocus 
    list="filllList">

  <div class="searchListarea">
    <ul id="filllList" *ngIf="searchResults.length > 0 && showResults">            
      <li 
        *ngFor="let item of searchResults" 
        (click)="selectItem(item)">
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>            
    </ul>
  </div>
</span>
```

NOTE: In the template I'm just searching via the `name` property but you can implement a dropdown that shows the fields by which the search could be performed and do the needful.

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zn1b6?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: thank you for your response i could achieve this through .ts file which working fine but only concern is i dont click enter everytime, only on key entry is should pop up the list automatically when there are matching entries exists, if not we should hide the list can u help me achieving this? @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 0):

This way you can check if the searchcontent has some content

```html
<div class="searchListarea" *ngIf="searchcontent">
     <!-- your ul list -->
</div>
```